# When is the order mail supposed to be sent in a custom payment method?

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

I am debugging a legacy shop where the former developer integrated a custom payment method.

Problem is, that the order mail is not sent.

I traced the references to `\Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail` and `\Mage_Sales_Model_Order::queueNewOrderEmail` and can not find anything but in PayPal express how it should be called.

How is the sending the confirmation mail process supposed to work? Am I supposed to  trigger it myself in a custom payment method or is it handled by the Magento order status  / state ?

Clarification: Sending mails is generally working (I configured cron, sending from the backend works)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the payment method does not use a redirect, the mail is sent in

`\Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder`

```
public function saveOrder()

...

      if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
            try {
                $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
```